# R Avoid x axis beeing automatically power of ten scaled

Tags: r, plot

R automatically uses powers of ten for the x axis (values are from zero to 500000) - but i want just the plain figures in steps of 50000 or something (NOT written as powers of ten).
I tried to set the axis with `axis(1,c(0,100000,....))` but it is plotted as powers of ten again.

I tried to scale down the font with cex.axis but it still uses power of ten for the x-axis. I think R tries to secure enough space between the values on the x-axis - but i want to force the full values to be plotted.

Axis looks at the moment like this:
-4e+05 -2e+05 0e+00 2e+05 4e+04 and so on ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This link seems to answer your question: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/09/12499.html

e.g. `option(scipen=6)` would make the cutoff for scientific notation only for numbers larger than 1e6 I believe.